# Manipulate NavMesh settings to include more area or tighter spaces in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the sphere to navigate itself to either of the two colored squares in the corners. however, as you can see, the nav mesh area is not allowing the system to recognize those paths as available for the agent. what are the settings that I need to change to allow the navmesh system to process the entirety of the map? Like, ALLLL the way to the edges of the map as well as up to the edges of the obstacles? (this is my first unity game, apologies if this is a simple question). Also, this image is just the "y-view" of a 3d game, this is not in 2d. I should also note that the sphere does successfully navigate to the closest corner to the cubes' positions, just not to the cube itself while avoiding the gray obstacles.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer came by changing the agent radius from .5 to .1

[image]